# Customize Android Spinner XML w/ SpinnerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I am using source code from GitHub, am trying to edit the look of the spinner. The only reference to a Spinner was in this java file and I can't find where I can set a custom layout XML for the spinner. Here is the java file:

```
package com.wallpaper.core;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

private final String TAG = "Adapter";
private final OnGetViewListener mListener;
private ArrayList<?> mData;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public static interface OnGetViewListener {
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater mInflater);
}

public Adapter (OnGetViewListener listener, Activity activity) {
    this.mData = new ArrayList<Object>();
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public Adapter (OnGetViewListener listener, Activity activity, ArrayList<?> data) {
    this.mData = (data == null) ? new ArrayList<Object>() : data;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public ArrayList<?> getData () {
    return this.mData;
}

public void setData (ArrayList<?> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}

public void clearData () {
    this.mData.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount () {
    if (mData == null)
        Log.d(TAG, "getCount() Data Set Is Null");
    return (mData != null) ? mData.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem (int position) {
    if (mData == null)
        Log.d(TAG, "getItem(int position) Data Set Is Null");
    return (mData != null) ? mData.get(position) : null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId (int position) {
    if (mData == null)
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemId(int position) Data Set Is Null");
    return (mData != null) ? position : 0;
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return (mListener == null) ? new LinearLayout(mInflater.getContext()) : this.mListener.getView(position, convertView, parent, mInflater);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return (mListener == null) ? new LinearLayout(mInflater.getContext()) : this.mListener.getView(position, convertView, parent, mInflater);
}

}
```

Comment: Find where the adapter is set to the spinner. You can modify the looks of the spinner there.

Answer (score 0):

Define your spinner where you want it

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_button_dropdown"
        ></Spinner>
```

As a spinner_button_dropdown you can use a selector like this (I know you're not asking for this but it shows how to customize the look):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal" android:state_focused="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal" />

</selector>
```

in your code you inflate it

```
mySpinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

As you can see, the look of the spinner in this example is not set from within, but user 3249477 said, from outside. Hope it helps you get going.